# Classification of principal monodromy elements

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $(X,0)$ be a germ of normal analytic space with an isolated singularity at $0$, and let $Y:=X\backslash\{0\}$. Suppose $Y$ has a complex-hyperbolic metric which is complete at $0$. Burns-Mazzeo proved in the paper entitled "On the geometry of cusps for SU(n,1)" that $(X,0)$ is biholomorphically isometric to a standard cusp for $SU(n,1)$.

Let $\pi:\tilde X\rightarrow X$ be a resolution of singularities with $\pi^{-1}(0)=E=\cup E_i$ the exceptional divisor with normal crossings. Consider a point $p\in E_i\backslash \cup_{j\neq i}E_i\cap E_j$. Then locally at $p$ there are holomorphic coordinates $(\zeta^1,\cdots,\zeta^n)$ such that $E=E_i$ locally, and $E_i$ is given by $\zeta^1=0$. Let $\gamma_i$ denote the element of $\pi_1(Y)$ determined by going once counterclockwise around $\zeta^1=0$. The element $\rho(\gamma_i)$ is called the principal monodromy element associated to the componnent $E_i$ of $E$.

In Burns-Mazzeo's paper (page 116 the last sentence in the paragraph above formula (2.5)) it claims that $\rho(\gamma_i)$ turns out to be one the two cases: the Elliptic case and the Parabolic case. My question is that why it holds? Is it by a standard argument in hyperbolic geometry？Can some show me how to understand this argument?

Thanks a lot for your reading!